# How to set Java language level to 8 in JetBrains Fleet?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-fleet

I can't find the config to set Java language level.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might find the answer here [How to change project language level for all project in Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915259/how-to-change-project-language-level-for-all-project-in-intellij)

Change the `sourceCompality` to `1.8`, if it didn't work, also change the Project structure JDK.

Comment: could not find the config

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven, in `pom.xml` file use:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

If you are using Gradle, in `build.gradle` file use:

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

Comment: i have set ,but it does't not work

Comment: Do you use Maven or Gradle? What exactly have you set and in which file(s)? How many modules do you have?